# Custom Model Field for formatting char field data

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm looking to have a specific model field that handles a factory_id in the format of `1234-12345`.

So that if a user tries to add a factory id that is just `XXXXXXXXX` or `XXXX-XXXXX` it will auto-magically store it in the database as `XXXX-XXXXX`.
Anyone point me in the direction as to where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rod Xavier said, you can use a `RegexValidator` for that. But, to be more precise, with a regex, you can allow both `XXXX-XXXXX` and `XXXXXXXXX` and then when you are saving format it with the dash if it is missing. If the entry is not 9 characters long or it is 10 characters without a dash, the `RegexValidator` will reject the field and the object won't be saved.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models 

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Notice the ? in the regex.
    factory_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                                  validators=[
                                      RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{5}$')
                                  ])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ This step is just formatting: add the dash if missing """
        if '-' not in self.factory_id:
            self.factory_id = '{0}-{1}'.format(
                 self.factory_id[:4], self.factory_id[4:])

        # Continue the model saving
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for this, however I'm just getting errors whilst using this. `error at /dash/add multiple repeat` also you should be using CharField not Charfield (for people using this as reference :))

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman Both things fixed. I didn't noticed the redondant `{0,1}` in fact...

Comment: fantastic, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Django's built-in Regex validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#regexvalidator). `from django.core.validators import RegexValidator`

**Example**

```
factory_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                              validators=[
                                  RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{4}-{0,1}[0-9]{5}$')
                              ])
```

Since you want to save the field in XXXX-XXXXX format. You should then alter the model's `save()` method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if '-' not in self.factory_id:
        self.factory_id = '{0}-{1}'.format(self.factory_id[:4], self.factory_id[4:])
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```